# TDengine ERROR (8000000b): Unable to establish connection

Tags: database, mybatis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhqRi.png)I'm  learning to use taos JDBC in myBatis project, and when  I using the demo provide by TDengine. I met this problem unable to establish connection.
sql:`insert into db1.t1(ts,temperature) values (now,23.23)`
The exception was thrown while calling on execute this sql command.
I tried to run the sql in command line on the server , it is ok.
while ran on my windows client it failed.
Running env
server: TDengine 2.1.3.2 on ubuntu 18.4
client: window x64
taos-jdbcdriver：2.0.32

loginfo

```
2021-07-22 16:00:48.116 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.dropSuperTable               : ==>  Preparing: drop table if exists temperature 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.130 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.dropSuperTable               : ==> Parameters: 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.139 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.dropSuperTable               : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.140 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.createSuperTable             : ==>  Preparing: CREATE TABLE if not exists temperature(ts timestamp, temperature float) tags(location nchar(64), tbIndex int) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.141 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.createSuperTable             : ==> Parameters: 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.161 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.createSuperTable             : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.163 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.164 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t0(String), 杭州(String), 0(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.226 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.227 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.228 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t1(String), 深圳(String), 1(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.242 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.243 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.243 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t2(String), 上海(String), 2(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.265 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.266 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.266 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t3(String), 上海(String), 3(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.286 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.287 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.287 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t4(String), 深圳(String), 4(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.301 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.302 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.302 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t5(String), 北京(String), 5(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.323 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.324 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.324 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t6(String), 杭州(String), 6(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.339 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.340 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.341 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t7(String), 深圳(String), 7(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.360 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.361 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.361 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t8(String), 深圳(String), 8(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.375 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.376 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==>  Preparing: create table ? using temperature tags( ?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.376 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : ==> Parameters: t9(String), 北京(String), 9(Integer)
2021-07-22 16:00:48.403 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.createTable  : <==    Updates: 0
2021-07-22 16:00:48.423 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.insertOne    : ==>  Preparing: insert into t0(ts, temperature) values(?, ?) 
2021-07-22 16:00:48.423 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.TemperatureMapper.insertOne    : ==> Parameters: 2020-11-11 00:00:00.0(Timestamp), 3.1568499(Float)
2021-07-22 16:00:57.045 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.dropSuperTable               : ==>  Preparing: drop table if exists temperature 
2021-07-22 16:00:57.045 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.dropSuperTable               : ==> Parameters: 
2021-07-22 16:00:57.071 DEBUG 16276 --- [           main] c.t.e.m.m.T.dropSuperTable               : <==    Updates: 0

org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: TDengine ERROR (8000000b): Unable to establish connection
### The error may exist in com/taosdata/example/mybatisplusdemo/mapper/TemperatureMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.taosdata.example.mybatisplusdemo.mapper.TemperatureMapper.insertOne-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into t0(ts, temperature) values(?, ?)
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: TDengine ERROR (8000000b): Unable to establish connection

    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:199)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:278)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.execute(MybatisMapperMethod.java:58)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.insertOne(Unknown Source)
    at com.taosdata.example.mybatisplusdemo.mapper.TemperatureMapperTest.before(TemperatureMapperTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: TDengine ERROR (8000000b): Unable to establish connection
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBError.createSQLException(TSDBError.java:73)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBJNIConnector.executeQuery(TSDBJNIConnector.java:123)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBStatement.execute(TSDBStatement.java:85)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBPreparedStatement.execute(TSDBPreparedStatement.java:266)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:47)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.doUpdate(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:54)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
    ... 41 more
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhqRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this demo on my pc. it worked correctly.

```
unable to establish connection
```

this exception is always cause by network problem. but from you log info, it seemed that you can access to the TDengine.It is hard to say what caused this.

I advise that you can open the debug flag, and try to figure out what going on there.

you follow these steps to debug you TDengine and read the debug log
which normally is very useful.
for windows

```
{TDengine_home}/cfg/tao.cfg
```

add "debugFlag 135", Then run your demo code again and read your client log on

```
{TDengine_home}/log/taoslog.*
```

find your sql and you can find the error

Comment: follow are my taoslog.0 error info, can you help me figure out what happened?

Comment: 00009236 RPC TSC 0000022A295E7798 000000000000000A, re-send msg:submit to localhost.localdomain:6030
 00009236 RPC TSC 0000022A295E7798 000000000000000A, submit is sent to localhost.localdomain:6030, len:158 sig:0x05000000:0x00000000:6335
 00009236 RPC TSC 0000022A295E7798 000000000000000A, expected submit-rsp is not received
 00009236 RPC TSC 0000022A295E7798 000000000000000A, failed to send msg:submit to localhost.localdomain:6030
 00009236 RPC TSC 0000022A295E7798 000000000000000A, rpc connection is released
 00009236 RPC TSC 000000000000000A, connection error happens

Comment: submit is sent to localhost.localdomain:6030, this is not work. I think you need to check your TDengine 's server config , /ect/config/taos.cgf check your FQDN, make sure that your client know there where that fsqn is.

Answer (score 0):

The exception logs show that the error happened during statement.execute. You should have successfully created a connection object (e.g., createConnection).

```
at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBStatement.execute(TSDBStatement.java:85)
```

Did you use IP instead of hostname in your URL? Please use hostname since Tdengine latest versions require hostname. It may fail silently during creating connection and cause some weird problems.

Some other causes may be here in Tdengine FAQ.

[2. When encoutered with the error " Unable to establish connection ", what can I do?](https://www.taosdata.com/en/faq/index.php)